# Merging two datasets on approximate values

Tags: r, dataset

I need to merge (left join) two data sets `x` and `y`.

```
merge(x,y, by.x = "z", by.y = "zP", all.x = TRUE)
```

Every value of `z` is not there in `zP` but there must be nearest value in `zP`. So we need to use nearest value in `zP`  for process of merging.
For example

```
z <- c(0.231, 0.045, 0.632, 0.217, 0.092, ...)
zP <- c(0.010,0.013, 0.017, 0.021, ...)
```

How can we do it in R ?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example and your desired output. Otherwise it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: ...and then put that reproducible exampe on stackoverflow because this isn't a very data sciency question and there's about a million more R users on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided it sounds like you want to keep all the observations in `x`, and then for each observation in `x` you want to find the observation in `y` that minimizes the distance between columns `z` and `zP`.  If that is what you are looking for then something like this might work

```
> library(data.table)

> x <- data.table(z = c(0.231, 0.045, 0.632, 0.217, 0.092), k = c("A","A","B","B","B"))
> y <- data.table(zP = c(0.010, 0.813, 0.017, 0.421), m = c(1,2,3,4))

> x
       z k 
1: 0.231 A 
2: 0.045 A 
3: 0.632 B 
4: 0.217 B 
5: 0.092 B 
> y
      zP m
1: 0.010 1
2: 0.813 2
3: 0.017 3
4: 0.421 4

> find.min.zP <- function(x){
+   y[which.min(abs(x - zP)), zP]
+ }

> x[, zP := find.min.zP(z), by = z]

> x
   z k    zP
1: 0.231 A 0.421
2: 0.045 A 0.017
3: 0.632 B 0.813
4: 0.217 B 0.017
5: 0.092 B 0.017

> merge(x, y, by="zP", all.x = T, all.y = F)
      zP     z k m
1: 0.017 0.045 A 3
2: 0.017 0.217 B 3
3: 0.017 0.092 B 3
4: 0.421 0.231 A 4
5: 0.813 0.632 B 2
```

This is the solution that popped into my head given that I use `data.table` quite a bit.  Please note that using `data.table` here may or may not be the most elegant way and it may not even be the fastest way (although if `x` and `y` are large some solution involving `data.table` probably will be the fastest).  Also note that this is likely an example of using `data.table` "badly" as I didn't make any effort to optimize for speed.  If speed is important I would highly recommend reading the helpful documentation on the [github wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).  Hope that helps.

Edit:

As I suspected, `data.table` provides a much better way, which Arun pointed out in the comments.

```
> setkey(x, z)
> setkey(y, zP)
> y[x, roll="nearest"]

      zP m k
1: 0.045 3 A
2: 0.092 3 B
3: 0.217 3 B
4: 0.231 4 A
5: 0.632 2 B
```

The only difference is that the `z` column is now named `zP` and the original `zP` column is gone.  If preserving that column is important you can always copy the `zP` column in `y` to a new column named `z` and join on that.

```
> y[, z := zP]
> setkey(x, z)
> setkey(y, z)
> y[x, roll='nearest']
      zP m     z k
1: 0.017 3 0.045 A
2: 0.017 3 0.092 B
3: 0.017 3 0.217 B
4: 0.421 4 0.231 A
5: 0.813 2 0.632 B
```

This is slightly less typing, but the real improvement is in compute times with large datasets.

```
> x <- data.table(z = runif(100000, 0, 100), k = sample(LETTERS, 100000, replace = T))
> y <- data.table(zP = runif(50000, 0, 100), m = sample(letters, 50000, replace = T))

> start <- proc.time()
> x[, zP := find.min.zP(z), by = z]
> slow <- merge(x, y, by="zP", all.x = T, all.y = F)
> proc.time() - start
  user  system elapsed 
104.849  0.072 106.432 

> x[, zP := NULL] # Drop the zP column we added to x doing the merge the slow way
> start <- proc.time()
> y[, z := zP]
> setkey(x, z)
> setkey(y, z)
> fast <- y[x, roll='nearest']
> proc.time() - start
 user  system elapsed 
0.046   0.000   0.045

# Reorder the rows and columns so that we can compare the two data tables
> setkey(slow, z)
> setcolorder(slow, c("z", "zP", "k", "m"))
> setcolorder(fast, c("z", "zP", "k", "m"))
> all.equal(slow, fast)
TRUE
```

Notice, that the faster method is 2,365 times faster!  I would expect the time gains to be even more dramatic for a data set with more than 100,000 observations (which is relatively small these days).  This is why reading the `data.table` documentation is worth while if you are working with large data sets.  You can often achieve very large speed ups by using the built in methods, but you won't know that they're there unless you look.

Comment: Nice answer. But, it can be done using *rolling joins* using `roll = "nearest"`. Set key on `x` and `y` to `z` and `zP` and do: `y[x, roll="nearest"]`. That's it.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the tip! I hadn't used the rolling joins before, but I'm glad I know about them now.  I updated the answer to show your suggestion and to show how much faster the rolling join is on a large data set.  Also, thanks for the great new github wiki, the documentation is much improved.  I really appreciate all the work you guys put into the package.  I find it incredibly useful for so many things.

Comment: Joseph, thanks. Yes, we're working on adding detailed vignettes for joins, overlapping joins and reshaping next. Hopefully we'll get there soon :-).