# Approximate join with random selection in reference table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I do have a data set `N` I would like to join with a reference table `REF`. The issue is that in the data set I do not have a proper primary key. My idea was to use a work around acknowledging its drawbacks. Thus I will use a numeric variable to find an approximate match and join it to the data set. 
I have tried [Merging two datasets on approximate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527964/merging-two-datasets-on-approximate-values) and tried to adapt it but failed. The tricky bit seems the data and the random selection in the reference table of the similar 1 values:

```
N <- data.table(NR = c( "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999"),
  year = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012"),
  los  = c( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

REF <- data.table(nr  =c( "A60D", "A91Z", "B70H", "B78C", "E64D", "F49F", "I66E", "I68E", "J68Z", "K63C", "L70A", "L70B", "L71Z", "O64B", "P60A", "P60C", "R65A", "R65B", "S60Z", "U60A", "U60B", "W60Z", "Y63Z"),
     alos = c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.4, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.0))
```

This example generates consequentially more data - but I cannot get around the proper selection and foremost a solution for picking the reference to 1 at random.

```
REF[, los := alos]
setkey(N, los)
setkey(REF, alos)
NEW <- N[REF, roll='nearest']

Desired output one row per row in N:

NR    year  los    nr   alos
999   2012   1     A60D   1.0
999   2012   1     A91Z   1.0
999   2012   1     A91Z   1.0
999   2012   1     W60Z   1.3
999   2012   1     P60C   1.4
999   2012   1     A91Z   1.0
```

Comment: How do you picture your desired output from this?

Comment: I added a possible excerpt - the distribution can be random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. I tried playing around with roll joins but I don't think you can get the random behaviour:

```
setkey(REF,alos)

N[, dif := min(abs(los - REF[, alos])), by = row.names(N)]

set.seed(123)
N[ , nr := REF[J(los-dif,los+dif),list(sample(nr,1))], by = row.names(N)]
N

     NR year los row dif   nr
 1: 999 2012   1   1   0 F49F
 2: 999 2012   1   2   0 R65B
 3: 999 2012   1   3   0 J68Z
 4: 999 2012   1   4   0 U60A
 5: 999 2012   1   5   0 U60B
 6: 999 2012   1   6   0 A60D
 7: 999 2012   1   7   0 L70A
 8: 999 2012   1   8   0 U60A
 9: 999 2012   1   9   0 L70B
10: 999 2012   1  10   0 K63C
11: 999 2012   1  11   0 Y63Z
12: 999 2012   1  12   0 K63C
13: 999 2012   1  13   0 O64B
14: 999 2012   1  14   0 L70B
15: 999 2012   1  15   0 B70H
```

All this code does is figure out which values in REF[, alos] are closest to the key value in N. Then it takes a random sample from that value in nr. I've left in `row` and `dif` but you can get rid of this seperately

Comment: Thanks for your endeavours. I played around and struggle with performance. As soon as I will find an improvement I will post it.